# Repository and query objects pattern. How to implement complex queries

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, design-patterns

I have read a lot of posts of the repository pattern but there are a few practical problems that they doesn't seem to solve or explain. This is what I understand about this two patterns:

**The repository and the query pattern are complementary:** Query objects represents business logic (WHERE clauses) and the repository pattern has a Get(IPredicate) method that takes a query object and returns a SELECT WHERE  result

**The repository should not have business logic:** All the business logic must go on the query objects

Currently I have a class that wraps each logical object (which almost always is a single entity object) that implements multiple "Get" methods that implement most complex queries (joins, groupBy, etc...), this isn't a good pattern because classes tend to grow a lot because of boilerplate code for similar queries and its public methods are dependent on context that this class will be used,  thus, making this classes unusable for multiple projects that depends on the same database, which is my primary goal for this project refactoring.

**How queries that are more complex than a single SELECT WHERE are implemented with this two patterns without leaking business logic into the repository?**

Or if this business logic doesn't fit into the repository nor the query objects
*where does this logic fit?*

Comment: Thanks, this is not my first language, I will correct the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few implementations of repository patterns and unit of work flying around on the internet. Some of them are quite simple where developer basically implements his own for each table himself manually, some are generic but not advanced, and some are really cool, generic and still offer you the ability to do a decent where, projection and the like.

An example of an in my opinion good implementation can be found here :

https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/

It is targetting MVC, which is shown by the interface. I am focussing on WPF applications so I needed to tune it a bit. But the ideas of this unit of work implementation are pretty good.

There is down side to this implementation. Because it is relying on some advanced LINQ and EF functionality one could argue that your underlying access layer is infecting the repository layer and the layers using the repositories.

The point being that when for instance you want to move away from EF, chances are that you would have to change the interface of your repositories.

To show the power of this library some code snippets to prove this :

```
_fotoRepository = unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<Foto>();
var fotos = await _fotoRepository
            .Query(r => r.BestelBonId == bestelBonId || werkstukids.Contains(r.WerkstukMetBewerkingenId.Value))
            .SelectAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

or using projection:

```
IRepository<Relatie> relatieRepository = unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<Relatie>();
        var relatiesOverviewsEnumerable = relatieRepository
            .Query()
            .NoTracking()
            .OrderBy(q => q.OrderBy(d => d.RelatieId))
            .Select(b => new RelatieOverview
            {
                RelatieId = b.RelatieId,
                Naam = b.Naam,
                BTW = b.BTW,
                HoofdAdres = b.Adressen.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AdresTypeId == HoofdadresType)
            });
        _relatieOverviews = new ObservableCollection<RelatieOverview>(relatiesOverviewsEnumerable);
```

Comment: How does the unitOfWork objet relates to the IUnitOfWork interface shown here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) ?, as I understand, the unit of work is used for changing the data, thus the MakeDirty, MakeNew, and MakeDeleted methods, while the Repository pattern is used for getting IQueryables data from the database

Answer (score 5):

The **Repository** pattern works well for standard CRUD applications. Where you need to implement the classic set of create, read, update and delete operations against a single table in a database. In that case you create a repository for each table and allow the read operation to have extra values so that filtering can be applied.

At the next level up you have the **Unit of Work** pattern. These are used to span multiple repositories and perform business operations. So for example, you would read values from multiple repositories, perform calculations and then write back changes to multiple repositories. All of that would occur inside a transaction so that you always have a consistent state in the database.

The problem is when you have complex queries that span multiple tables. In that case you would place the query into the repository that is the first table in the query *from* clause. Then you would need to provide parameters to that repository method so it can be parameterised as needed.

Comment: So the unit of work pattern is used in method across multiple classes that need to do the business logic?

Comment: Do you know what has worked really well for decades at querying databases? SQL. Call me jaded, but these Repository and Unit of Work patterns seem over-architected and lacking in benefit

Comment: The Repository will contain the actual SQL. Unit of Work contains the transaction logic around what will be multiple SQL commands from the Repositories. I agree that if you never need to worrying about migrating to another database backend then you often don't need these patterns.

Comment: You got it right until the last paragraph of your answer. Modern ORMs (EF & NHibernate) have no problem spanning across multiple tables. The challenge of UoW is not to write multiple entries in different tables, the ORM already does it. The goal is to provide "automatic" (implemented by you) rollback if one of the steps fails.

Comment: I agree with @Manachi, this is over-engineered and doesn't scale with complex queries. I have tried writing complex joins with LINQ and other abstractions, and it was a nightmare. In SQL it takes a couple of seconds or minutes to write a complex join between 5 tables. Using repositories where this is all split up and then joined back together in a unit of work would probably take 2 hours and then it would be a nightmare to maintain and comprehend. 
Somehow it seems the people who come up with these solutions usually work with tiny databases and have no clue how to work with data warehouses.